# Area swept by vertex angles in an irregular polygon.

Tags: geometry, polygons

Given **any general n-gon**, what is the minimum number of vertex angles that sweep the whole area of the polygon?

That is to say, what should be the least number of vertices a person has to stand at in order to look at the whole area of the n-gon?

Comment: Have you read this?: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem

Comment: thank you so much! I wish I could upvote your comment.

Comment: also, is there a simpler proof than using dual graphs?

Comment: @JimmyK4542: Do you want to turn that comment into an answer, providing the link and a short summary?

Comment: yes, i'd love to see that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the [Art gallery problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem).

For a simple $n$-gon, it has been proven that you can always select a set of $\left\lfloor\tfrac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ vertices such that every point in the $n$-gon is viewable from one of these vertices. There are simple $n$-gons for which selecting $\left\lfloor\tfrac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ vertices is necessary, that is we cannot select a smaller set of vertices, and still view every point from one of the selected vertices. For example, in the polygon shown in [the first image here](http://eric.gruver.net/ArtGalleryProblems.html), no camera can see more than one of the triangular prongs, so $\left\lfloor\tfrac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$ vertices are needed. You can create an example for any $n = 3k$ by having $k$ prongs instead of $4$. For any $n = 3k+1$ or $n = 3k+2$, use $k$ prongs and chop off $1$ or $2$ of the bottom corners.

There are other extensions of this problem, for which nice results are known. If all the angles in the $n$-gon are $90^{\circ}$ or $270^{\circ}$, then only $\left\lfloor\tfrac{n}{4}\right\rfloor$ vertices are needed. Also, if a simple $n$-gon has $h$ interior "holes" for which we cannot see through, then $\left\lfloor\tfrac{n+h}{3}\right\rfloor$ vertices are needed.

Comment: so, is it just mere observation? Not that it's a bad approach, but is there a proof not using the 3-coloring method?

Comment: I believe all of those facts I stated have been proven. You can probably find a proof online if you search for one.